# PHP Split array by Key -> Valuue

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that contains some data and I want to split it by year to get subarrays with YEAR as value and array of items with same year as key.
Start array looks like:

```
$arr = [
   0 => Array(
     'name' => 'Some name',
     'description' => 'some description',
     'year' => 2019
   ),
   1 => Array(
     'name' => 'Some name 1',
     'description' => 'some description 1',
     'year' => 2020
   ),
   2 => Array(
     'name' => 'Some name 2',
     'description' => 'some description 2',
     'year' => 2020
   ),
];
```

And I want to get an array splited by Year like this:

```
$arr = [
  '2019' => Array(
      0 => Array(
         'name' => 'Some name',
         'description' => 'some description',
         'year' => 2019
       ),
  ),
  '2020' => Array(
       0 => Array(
         'name' => 'Some name 1',
         'description' => 'some description 1',
         'year' => 2020
       ),
       1 => Array(
         'name' => 'Some name 2',
         'description' => 'some description 2',
         'year' => 2020
       ),
  ),
];
```

What PHP function can do this?

Comment: This is not really difficult, did you try anything for yourself yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to group them by year which can be achieved through something like the following

```
$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $element) {
    $result[$element['year']][] = $element;
}
```